# std::byte bitwise operators |, &, ^, ~: why cast to unsigned int?

Tags: c++, c++17, bitwise-operators, std-byte

According to `std::byte`'s documentation on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte), the implementation of  `operator|` for `std::byte` should be equivalent to

```
constexpr std::byte operator|(std::byte l, std::byte r) noexcept
{
    return std::byte{ static_cast<unsigned>(l) | static_cast<unsigned>(r) };
}
```

(Operators `&`, `^`, `~` should be implemented similarly)

Why do `l` and `r` need to get cast to `int unsigned` if `std::byte`'s underlying type is `char unsigned`?

**Note:** I'm aware that `char unsigned{} | char unsigned{}` results in an `int` because each operand gets promoted to `int` before the *bitwise or* is applied; while `unsigned{} | unsigned{}` returns an `unsigned` and no promotion happens. However, I don't understand which issues may such a promotion cause in this context.

Comment: note that the operands of `char unsigned{} | char unsigned{}` will be promoted to `unsigned int` in case `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)`. They aren't always promoted to `int`

Comment: @phuclv Thanks, I didn't know that. This makes that `static_cast` even more confusing to me.

Comment: It would be relatively unusual for `unsigned char` to have the same size as `int`; it's normally only seen on specialized hardware like DSPs that only handle word-sized operations and not bytes.  But in that unusual case, the `static_cast` would just be redundant, so it doesn't really affect this question.

Answer (score 2):

For integer types that are smaller then an `int`, they are promoted to an `int` before the operator is applied.  That means if you had

```
return std::byte{ l | r };
```

then you would have a signed integer.  By using

```
return std::byte{ static_cast<unsigned>(l) | static_cast<unsigned>(r) }
```

You explicitly convert the operands to unsigned integers so that no promotion to `int` happens.

This could make a difference before C++20 as signed integers were not required to use a two's complement representation unlike unsigned integer types.

Comment: Can you provide a case where it can make a difference?

Comment: @paolo I'm not that familiar with non-twos complement representations so I don't have a concrete example I can give you.

Comment: According to cppreference `std::byte` isn't a numeric type and doesn't have type casting operators, so it's unclear how those casts even work.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I was confused by that too, but I think it's meant as an informal description, to be read as if `l,r` were actually `unsigned char`.

Comment: I was reaching the same conclusion, it's an illustration not real code.

Comment: That said, `static_cast<unsigned>(b)` actually does compile on all the compilers I tried, so I am not quite sure what is going on. https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @NateEldredge and Mark Ransom `std::byte` is an `enum class` and all enumerations can be explicitly casted to an integer type.  It's just that enum class doesn't allow an implicit conversion.

Comment: @paolo: At least by casting to `unsigned` you avoid having to worry at all about possible strange corner cases with signed integer representations.  I would guess they chose `unsigned` here just to conform with that practice, and didn't really think about whether it was truly necessary.  (I also don't know whether it is.)